# Android WebView Disable Iframe Loading

Tags: java, android, html, android-webview

In my app I have an WebView which displays some webpages. 
Some webpages contain iframes. and some iframes load alertboxes, confirmboxes, prompts and popups.

I want to block loading that iframe but not loading it? or atleast disable these popups (without disabling javascript)

I tried to block these pages by filtering them by following method

```
in the on page started method 
use the if condition to match the url with the url which gives popups
if matched restart the webview
```

however i found that the url is always of the main site and not the site the iframe loads so if statement is never true

how do I block the iframe or popups?

any help would be appreciated

thankyou

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `WebViewClient` and override `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`.

Check if it's an iframe with `if (!request.isForMainFrame())`.
Then you can manually load the content of the url and sanitize it.

```
@TargetApi(24)
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
    if (!request.isForMainFrame()) {
        if (shouldBlock(request.getUrl()))
            return true;
    }
    return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request);
}
```

Comment: i found shouldOverrideUrlLoading not called if url contain target = newblank